# Oracle complex query help required

Tags: oracle

Can anyone help me getting the output data from oracle database with below conditions.

1.data for each mobile number with last updated ( latest date ) to be copied to an output file.

Note -- there can be multiple entries for single mobile number with different date.

TABLE STRUCTURE AS BELOW.

```
SQL> desc jtoom.mnp_port_nos_prbt_view;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 LSA                                                VARCHAR2(144)
 MSISDN                                             VARCHAR2(144)
 RECIPIENT                                          VARCHAR2(144)
 DONOR                                              VARCHAR2(144)
 LRN                                                VARCHAR2(144)
 DT_STAMP                                           DATE
```

Comment: Which column is the mobile number?

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this may work:

```
select column_name, max(dt_stamp) max_dt_stamp
from table_or_view
group by column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Column_Name, A.Dt_Stamp
FROM jtoom.mnp_port_nos_prbt_view A
WHERE A.Dt_Stamp = (SELECT Max(B.Dt_Stamp) FROM jtoom.mnp_port_nos_prbt_view B WHERE B.Column_Name = A.Column_Name)
```